# AWS EC2 get IP and name based on 2 filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

`JMESPath` is driving me crazy. I want to get the IP and name of machines with a `security group == "SG-DEV"`

What I came up with after 1 hour of reading documentations:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[] && SecurityGroups[?GroupName == 'SG-DEV'].PrivateIpAddress]"
```

It produces only the machine name, not only SG-DEV machines and not the IP address.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Use `filters` to list the instances that have `SG-DEV` as security group and then from the output extract only the private IP and the instance name. Getting the instance name is a bit tricky. Check the examples in: [Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

The following should return what you are asking for:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=instance.group-name,Values=SG-DEV" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress, Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value]" --output text
```

Answer (score 0):

The Private IP address is under a different namespace, you'll need to use a combination of the query and filter switches to get that.

`network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address` and `private-ip-address`

Change the value of `Values=SG-DEV`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=instance.group-name,Values=default" --query "Reservations[].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress[]"
```

It returns this list

```
[
    "10.0.1.202"
]
```

The filter can also filter on tags

> tag :key =*value* - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource. Specify the key of the tag in the filter name and the value of the tag in the filter value. For example, for the tag Purpose=X, specify 
>   tag:Purpose for the filter name and X for the filter value.
>
> tag-key - The key of a tag assigned to the resource. This filter is independent of the tag-value filter. For example, if you use both the filter "tag-key=Purpose" and the filter "tag-value=X", you get any resources assigned both the tag key Purpose (regardless of what the tag's value is), and the tag value X (regardless of what the tag's key is). If you want to list only resources where Purpose is X, see the tag :key =*value* filter.
>
> tag-value - The value of a tag assigned to the resource. This filter is independent of the tag-key filter.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

Comment: I need also the machine name with `.[Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[]` how can I add it?

Comment: The filter can also filter on tags